# Cant remove theme from settings windows and Nautilus after upgrading to 23.10

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, gnome-tweaks

I just upgraded from 23.04 to 23.10 and I was using the White Sur Theme but it seems to be a bit broken. There is no background in the nautilus file manager window. If I open a folder that is empty there is just no background. So I went to change the theme to one of the defaults and the panel and panel dropdowns change but the nautilus window remains the same. The themes is also stuck on the settings window and things like calculator and text editors. For some reason the system doesn't recognize that the theme has been changed.

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

As you can see my shell theme is set to yaru- dark but the nautilus window is still the old White Sur Nord theme. I don't know what is going on here but there has been quite a few bugs so far when upgrading to 23.10 but I can't figure out how to get rid of the old theme and this on has me stumped.

I have tried to delete the theme entirely and restart but it seems to be cached somewhere and deleting it and restarting doesn't do anything. So if anyone knows where this is being cached at or how I can remove this and change it to something that actually works I would really appreciate it.

Also just a side question feel free to ignore but if anyone knows how to set the background of the nautilus window in gnome 45 that would be good information to know because I have tried `.nautilus-window { background: #color }` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 is still in development, and will not be supported on this website before it is released (in October).

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 (*mantic*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *mantic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 5 October 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 12 October 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Ubuntu *mantic* is still in ***alpha***, having not yet progressed to *beta*, thus bugs are to be expected. The *alpha* product exists so early testers can *test* it and file bug reports. Please report all you see, as that helps them get fixed before the product reaches *beta* - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs